# How can i bind foreach data function to some observable array so that on changing the array values KO Foreach section also gets updated

Tags: magento2, checkout, knockoutjs

**Foreach Data Function getAvailableMethods**

```
<!-- ko foreach: { data: getAvailableMethods(), as: 'item' } -->
<label style="position: relative;top: 2px;"  data-bind="attr: {'for': item.code}" class="label"><span data-bind="text: item.name"></span></label>
<!-- /ko -->
```

**JS Code**

```
 getAvailableMethods: function (methods) {

  console.log(methods);

   return methods;

  },
```

Currently, there is empty data on initialization **ko foreach: { data: getAvailableMethods()**
But i want to populate the data every time variable **methods** gets updated
How can i apply the binding of function getAvailableMethods() with variable methods ?

**JS Code**

```
  'use strict';

  var methods = '';

 getPaymentMethodLists: function () {

  $.ajax({

    success: function (data) {

      methods = data.methods

    }

  },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It worked with the following way

Under payment.html

```
<!-- ko foreach: { data: getAvailableMethods(), as: 'item' } -->
<!-- /ko -->
```

Under payment-method.js

getAvailableMethods: function () {} which is getting the data via ajax request and it worked well.

Only problem occurs when there is some conditional logic error. Than, it breaks the flow of data binding, even though the object have updated data but the html section was not getting update.

Answer (score 0):

Use KnockoutJS observable array for that.

To initialise observable array, define your `methods` like this.

```
var methods = ko.observableArray();
```

And to populate `methods` with your AJAX response, you can use `push(value)` method, like this,

```
methods.push(method)
```

**Refer to [official documentation link](https://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observableArrays.html) for in depth details.**

Comment: Still not working